# How do I view the drives occupied by a hardware device?

Tags: windows

I have four card slots on my computer (for SD, CompactFlash, etc.), but ever since I installed Windows on my new SSD, I have not been able to rename the drives for each slot because I do not know which drive corresponds with what slot, so they're just aptly named `Removable Disk`.

I've looked in the Properties menu of these empty drives, but all I can find is a Hardware tab with no indication of which hardware device that drive corresponds to.

How can I determine what this is so that I can rename each drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to determine this, but you will need administrator access to do so.

1. Open up Disk Management (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open up Run, then `diskmgmt.msc`).
2. Scroll down on the graphical view (the bottom half of the window) until you see the unknown drive.
3. Right click the name of the disk and select `Properties`:
   [image: Right-click, then Properties]
4. The properties for the hardware device for that disk will be shown.

Now you can go to Computer and just hit F2 to rename each drive.